# Change VFOs with external mic button in Icon ID-51?

Tags: icom-id-51-plus2

Is it possible to configure a external mic, specifically, a Icom HM-75LS, to switch between the two VFOs when pressing a button on an Icon ID-51 Plus2?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.manualslib.com/manual/628105/Icom-Id-31a.html?page=65

> ■ Optional HM-75LS
>
> The optional HM-75LS allows you to remotely select operating frequencies, memory channels, etc.
>
> Remote control functions can be selected from three settings. These can be selected with "MIC Simple Mode" in the FUNCTION menu.
>
> **MENU ➪ FUNCTION ➪ MIC Simple Mode (p. 44)**
>
> The HM-75LS has a lock switch on the backside to prevent accidental frequency changes, and so on.
>
> **Be sure to turn power OFF when plugging or unplugging the HM-75LS to and from the [SP/MIC] jack.**
>
> - SIMPLE:
>   [A]Toggles the Monitor function
>   [B]Turns the Call channel mode
>   [p] Select memory channel 0
>   [q] Select memory channel 1
> - NORM-1: (default)
>   [A]Selects the Call channel mode
>   [B]Toggles the VFO mode and Memory mode
>   [p] Frequency or memory channel 'UP'
>   [q] Frequency or memory channel 'DOWN'
> - NORM-2:
>   [A]Turns the Monitor function
>   [B]Toggles the VFO mode and Memory mode
>   [p] Frequency or memory channel 'UP'
>   [q] Frequency or memory channel 'DOWN'
>
> The SIMPLE mode can select only three channels, and is useful for group operations during touring, and so on.
>
> **The VFO mode cannot be selected from the microphone when Simple mode is selected.**

It appears that it can change the VFO mode in the normal-2 mike mode but I did not see that it can change to the other VFO. I did not see any way to program it differently. There may be a method that I am not aware of but I doubt it.